# e-bay-like site: tags or categories?

Tags: categories

I know there is many debates on this subject, but still ... I can't make up my mind, so:

If you build a site similar to ebay (just imagine this is ebay), where objects and services can be bought or rented, would you use categories and sub-categories to classify all the objects/services, or rather tags ?

Comment: This really isnt a question for this site.  Its a purely opinion based question without a real answer(removing the RoR tag as it is not relevant, and the "tags" tag as it is a different use than what you are talking about)

Comment: @jzworkman Seconded. Not to mention there are already questions in the Related questions that are almost verbatim copies of this question.

Comment: Exactly, questions like this are just debates, OP needs to read the FAQ before posting this kind of stuff.

Comment: OK ok ... I guessed it could be too 'broad/opinion' as a question for this site ... just figured it out I could get interesting answers because it's a question that many people asks themselves, and there are answers but very broad and not specific to that case. Still ... I would have preferred a link to a pertinent answer to my question and getting a -4 score, than no real answer and 'your question is not appropriate' and -4 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no strict answer to this question. A tag or a category doesn't change the meaning of the object, it is just a feature of your site.

So if you tag a computer as electronics, you can also categorize it as electronics. Tags would add more meta description in addition to categories. Have you used WordPress before? Look at it. Category is central, and tagging is additional description, like keywords. They help in search, grouping, sets, etc.